# Query a large list of partition ids in dynamo db where partition key is unique

Tags: memory-management, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am new to dynamo db.

The table looks like below

```
| id   |rangekey |timestamp    |dimensions
| -----| --------|-------------|----------
| of1  | ACTIVE  |1631460979529|{"type":"test","content":"abc"}
| of2  | ACTIVE  |1631499979529|{"type":"test","content":"bxh"}
| of3  | ACTIVE  |1631499979520|{"type":"practice","content":"xyz"}
| of4  | ACTIVE  |1631499979528|{"type":"lecture","content":"lll"}
| of5  | ACTIVE  |1631460979927|{"type":"practice","content":"olp","component":"one"}
| ..   |..       |...          |...
```

so on.

The  **id** is the partition key and **range key** is the sort key.The **id** values are unique.

It seems like poorly designed table when it comes to querying all the **id** for which the **dimensions** contains (or begins with)

```
"type":"test" or "type":"practice"
```

I am aware of the below approaches:

1. Scan the table with filter expression like below

   ```
   contains(dimensions,'"type":"test"') or contains(dimensions,'"type":"practice"')
   ```
2. Query the partition id one
   by one with filter expression as above.This seems like a problem
   because i have a large list of **id** (partition keys) approx up-to
   5000 .But this  could be run in parallel to reduce time
3. Or can i create a dynamo db stream sort of a materialized view which has the
   view containing all **id** whose dimension is of type test or
   practice.Need more insight on this one.

Does any of the above approach seems good cost wise or efficiency.Are there better ways of doing this.Thanks in advance !